The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified deleted since entities were loaded
I have created the data model in run time using reflection till now the CRUD operation is working fine. But when tried to implement the optimistic concurrency it threw an error. I have created the dbcontext for every request because we have a feature that user can able to alter or create the table in run time so i need to make sure to get last updated schema version from the data base that's why i initiate the dbcontext for every request
public DynamicDbContext(DbContextOptions options, Action<ModelBuilder> onModelCreating, string cacheKey)
    : base(options)
{
    _onModelCreating = onModelCreating;
    _cacheKey = cacheKey;
}

public Type DynamicEntity { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    _onModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    var entitybuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(DynamicEntity);
    foreach (var propertyName in DynamicEntity.GetProperties())
    {
        if (propertyName.Name != "ID")
        {
            entitybuilder.Property(propertyName.Name).IsConcurrencyToken(true);
        }


    }
}


"I have created the data model in run time using reflection" - What do you mean by this?

entitybuilder.Property(propertyName.Name).IsConcurrencyToken(true); <-- ...why are you doing this and why do you think this is correct?

Without data model how the entity framework is working? I am not saying that I'm correct but i already achieved the crud operation using reflection. For example if you change the schema for a table in database how it will reflect in server side project?

You're meant to use scaffolding tooling (which is a dotnet CLI tool) - or you can use other scaffolding/templating tooling (like EFPOCO) which generates the C# EF entities and config from your database.

@Dai did they get that config in run time?

I don't understand your question, sorry.
